# Make systemd treat unexpected exit as failure

Tags: signals, exit-status, systemd-unit

I'm wrapping a 3rd party executable in a systemd service unit to manage it.  I can't alter the behavior of this program and I don't really trust its exit codes.  I would like to treat any exit that was not caused by systemd as a failure, that includes exit code 0 or an outside SIGTERM, so I can detect the difference through systemd's interfaces.

Currently my unit looks something like:

```ini
[Unit]
Description=Foo service
Requires=bar.service
After=bar.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/foo/foo -stayresident
KillMode=control-group
Restart=no
```

If I kill the service process manually, I get "inactive" when checking the state with `systemctl`

```sh
killall foo && systemctl status foo.service
```

If I upgrade that kill to `-9`, I get "failed":

```sh
killall -9 foo && systemctl status foo.service
```

This is the behavior I'd like to expand.

I know that the [`SuccessExitStatus=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#SuccessExitStatus=) service unit setting can be used to count non-zero exits and other failure types to be considered as success, but I don't see anything that would do the opposite.

Comment: Do you want to consider the proces exiting with any exit code to be a failure, or are there any that you would consider a successful termination?

Comment: I want any termination that systemd did not initiate to be considered failure.  Hence the desire to get '0' or termination by SIGTERM also counted as failure. I've edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: @davolfman You can make use of the environment variables `$SERVICE_RESULT`,  `$EXIT_CODE` and `$EXIT_STATUS`. Those values are passed to `ExecStop= and ExecStopPost=` proccess, Maybe that can help you to achieve what you want

Comment: @EdgarMagallon I'm not sure adding special ExecStop behavior will help in my particular case. But that could be a sound way to hack a solution out for someone else. Using systemd to track status instead of procfs gets rid of a whole script from my system and this kinda puts it back.

Comment: @EdgarMagallon it looks like ExecStopPost and ExecStop don't work.  I put an echo in there and it appeared in my systemd journal under the service after running killall.

Comment: @davolfman what did you get? In `ExecStop` or `ExecStopPost` you can create a custom (shell) script which reads the values of the environment variables (but certainly I'm not sure if that can help you to solve your problem). Also I considered to make all exits as success by prefixing `-`, like this `ExecStart=-/opt/foo/foo -stayresident` but I think that's not useful in this case

Comment: For both killall and systemctl stop the results are the same: `SERVICE_RESULT=success`, `EXIT_CODE=killed`, `EXIT_STATUS=TERM`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may not have understood what you need, but perhaps you can do something simple like adding a failing command after the `foo` command. This second command would not be run by `systemctl stop`. For example, replace the `ExecStart` with

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '/opt/foo/foo -stayresident && exit 7'
```

The choice of 7 is just so we can see it more clearly in the status.
If `foo` is killed by signal, or dies of its own accord, the shell process proceeds and results in an exit code of 7 and a systemd status of *failed*. If a `systemctl stop` is done the shell is killed, and the status is *inactive (dead)*. Making the `exit 7` only occur if the original command is successfull allows any failure signals `foo` naturally emits to be kept.

Note, to avoid `killall foo` also matching the `bash` command, you can use a subterfuge like `bash -c '/opt/"f"oo/"f"oo ...'`.

Comment: The 'self-destructing' ExecStart like that seems to work.  I'm guessing because the shutdown via killmode causes it to never reach the second shell call if systemd does the stopping. It even shows detectable differences in the systemd variables:
`SERVICE_RESULT=exit-code`, `EXIT_CODE=exited`, `EXIT_STATUS=7`
If nobody can come up with a way to do this within systemd semantics I'll probably accept this.

Comment: As an enhancement maybe the `;` could be swapped for an `&&` so that way you're just choosing what the exit code of an unexpected exit 0 is and maintain the ability to differentiate between other error codes.